# RESTful Java GET method

Tags: json, rest, getmethod

Could I send a request GET to a restful server,that contain a JSON object ?

In case that I can, how can I get it from server side ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Most restful servers working with data in JSON format (if not in parameter, or XML format). You can take a look at the example at the [jQuery page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/). You can also call publicly available services such as [Google weather](http://openweathermap.org/current) service.

Example of AJAX call with using the JSON data:

```
var data = { name: "John", time: "2pm" };
$.getJSON( "test.js",  data )
  .done(function( json ) {
    console.log( "JSON Data: " + json.users[1].name );
 })
```

Comment: I mean that the JSON is in the request made from client to server, not the JSON in the response from server to client.

Comment: So you must expose the content of the JSON in the url ?

Comment: Take a look at the first link (jQuery), there is a sample code for it.